# Collect the product and shipping price at the time of order processing

Tags: magento-1.9

My requirement is to collect the payment at the time of order processing.
 When a customer is placing an order, he is allowed to choose the payment option as 'Billed Later', ie no other payment details are asked to enter during order creation.

The product price and shipment charges will be known only at the time of Order processing. So while processing the order,Admin should be able to choose the payment details such as credit card details of the customer.

We are not allowed to save the payment details of the customer in our site (Like Saved Credit card).

Is there any payment gateways or methods available in market to satisfy my requirement. ie collect the credit card details from customer during order placement and allowed to choose the details by admin during order processing.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You'd definitely need some external payment processor to do that. But I'm not sure if any of them allows to charge the CC with another value that the customer has allowed the processor to charge.

Or to give a simple excample:

1. Customer accepts you or your processor to charge a value of $10 on their credit card
2. Processor and CC authorize $10 charge (without actually booking it)
3. You process the order and find out that $10 isn't enough, you'd need $10.50
4. --> You will need another customer authorization for the charge of $10.50

So I guess credit card won't work - one way or the other. I also cannot imagine any Payment Provider (PayPal, klarna, whoever) allowing this. They usually all want the definite total chargeable value for processing.

You probably can obtain customer's bank account information and ask them if it is okay for them to charge their bank accounts with a value that the customers don't know when ordering - but not sure if you're allowed to store that either.

I'm also not sure if anyone would buy things when the billing price's not final, or if this is actually legal in your country.